# Using Range(Cells() Cells()).Style results in application defined or user defined error

Tags: vba, excel

Curretly I'm trying to style a range of cells if certain criteria are met.  I am able to sucessfully apply a style to one cell, but have so far been unsuccessful in applying this to a range.  Here's what I know works:

```
ElseIf OneA / OneC > 0.8 And OneA / OneC <= 1 Then
      ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(StartYear & " " & StartQ & " - " & EndYear & " " & EndQ).Cells(Employee, StartCol).Style = "60% - Accent2"
```

This above code styles the cell (Employee, StartCol) to 60% - Accent2. However, when I change this code to try to apply the styling to a range, I get the "Application defined or user defined error".  Here's what I tried to change the code to:

```
ElseIf OneA / OneC > 0.8 And OneA / OneC <= 1 Then
                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(StartYear & " " & StartQ & " - " & EndYear & " " & EndQ).Range(Cells(Employee, StartCol), Cells(Employee + 49, StartCol)).Style = "60% - Accent2"
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I think it may be a syntax error, but I'm not experienced enough with vba to know where exactly it's going wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `Cells` global object in the second snippet, but explicitly referencing the `.Cells` property of the worksheet in the first snippet.  The second one will actually work, but only if the active worksheet ***matches*** the one you're getting from `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets()`. Grab a reference to the target worksheet, and then use ***its*** `.Cells` property instead of the global:

```
ElseIf OneA / OneC > 0.8 And OneA / OneC <= 1 Then
    Dim target As Worksheet
    Set target = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(StartYear & " " & StartQ & " - " & EndYear & " " & EndQ)
    With target
        .Range(.Cells(Employee, StartCol), .Cells(Employee + 49, StartCol)).Style = "60% - Accent2"
    End With
```